# Is buying a cheaper version of something commendable so less people are jealous of you?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, jealousy

If suppose instead of buying an expensive smartphone or car or house you bought an average priced one instead is this a good thing because less people will be jealous of you and thus you are causing less people to sin or rather is it their problem and test from Allah to face?

Answer (score 1):

[Forbidding evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enjoining_good_and_forbidding_wrong) is a good deed, the Prophet spoke out against jealousy (*do not be jealous of one another*, [Sahih al-Bukhari 6064](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/94)), and good deeds are magnified ([Qur'an 4:40](https://quran.com/4/40)) and judged by intention ([Sahih al-Bukhari 1](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/1/1)).  So even an attempt to thwart jealousy is commendable.

However, changing one's behavior in one way (not spending extravagantly), in order to provoke someone else to change their behavior in another way (not be jealous) seems too convoluted to likely work: your actions may have no discernible effect.

1. They might be jealous regardless, or
2. they might not be jealous, even if you make extravagant purchases.

However, the specifics of a situation affect the likelihood.

Regardless, there's a better reason to not be extravagant:

> And give the relative his right, and [also] the poor and the traveler, and **do not spend wastefully**.  Indeed, the wasteful are brothers of the devils, and ever has Satan been to his Lord ungrateful.
>   <sub>[Qur'an 17:26-27](https://quran.com/17/26-27)</sub>